# unknown command ':1' haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci

I just decided to get adventurous and learn some Haskell.   I am following along from http://learnyouahaskell.com/. I downloaded the whole Haskell Platform from http://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html for 64bit Mac Architecture, I already had gcc/command line tools installed, and am not running Mavericks yet.

GHCI runs great, but when I wrote the simple `doubleMe` exercise, and followed learnyouahaskell's directions to save and run the script, GHCI outputs the following error:
    `Prelude> :1 baby`
    `unknown command ':1'`
    `use :? for help.`

I'm wondering if this command is deprecated or if I'm reading the documentation from LearnYouAHaskell wrong.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

---

Thanks to @icktoofay for the syntax help and answering my question. Here is the original source that caused the confusion:

[image: Screenshot from learnyouahaskell]

And here is why numeral `1` and the lowercase letter `l` was confusing in iTerm:

[image: Screenshot from iTerm]

Comment:             ,   !

Answer (score 38, accepted):

GHCi understands `:load` or its abbreviation `:l`, not a colon followed by the numeral one.
A lowercase L and the digit 1 do look very similar, so I can understand your confusion.

Comment: That was exactly the case. the `:?` help command didn't even list `:load` as a command. Good catch, Thanks alot.

Comment: This is very relevant. What a damn joke. I had to come here to figure this out. Now I will go proceed to Learn Me a Haskell...

Comment: The font used in Learn Me a Haskell doesn't help.